# SQLDataReader is not returning any data

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I am connecting to a SQLExpress server and trying to return data from a table.  The code is making the connection but when I read the results from my query there is no data.  I have executed the query in SSMS and it works just fine.  I also use the same code in another application and it works fine.  I am so confused right now.  Here is my connection routine:

```
private void ConnectToDatabase()
    {
        string strConnection = null;


        try
        {
            if (sqlConn != null)
            {
                sqlConn.Close();
            }


            strConnection = "Data Source=CASS-LAPTOP\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=NBFoodPantry;Integrated Security=true";

            sqlConn = new SqlConnection(@strConnection);
            try
            {
                sqlConn.Open();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string strMsg;

                strMsg = "ConnectToDatabase: SQL Open failed with error, " + ex.Message + ".";
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(strMsg);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string strMsg;

            strMsg =" ConnectToDatabase: failed with error, " + ex.Message  + ".";
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(strMsg);
        }
    }
```

Here is the code to query the table:

```
private void LoadCitys()
    {
        bool blnSuccess = false;
        int intItemCnt;
        string strQuery;


        if (sqlConn != null && sqlConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            intItemCnt = 0;
            strQuery = "select distinct city from zipcodes order by city";

            try
            {
                using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, sqlConn))
                {
                    SqlDataReader sqlDataRead = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (sqlDataRead.Read())
                    {
                        string strDBNme = sqlDataRead.GetString(intItemCnt);
                        cmbxACCity.Items.Add(strDBNme);
                    }

                    sqlDataRead.Close();
                    sqlCmd.Dispose();
                    cmbxACCity.SelectedItem = cmbxACCity.Items.GetItemAt(0);
                }

                blnSuccess = true;
            }
            catch (Exception exQuery)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("LoadCitys: Error, " + exQuery.Message + ", has occurred.");
                blnSuccess = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: any exception coming?

Comment: how far do you get when debugging? does it ever enter the while loop? what's the syntax with "@strConnection" in the `SqlConnection` ctor?

Comment: I am so confused right now.  I just ran the application again to double check if an exception was thrown and get that message and not it is working.  I have no idea why.  Thank you for helping.

Comment: Do you definitely get a database connection, without that it just drops through - put some more message boxes in to tell you if the database has been connected to or not, can you run it in debug and hit the breakpoints?

Comment: nothings wrong on your code. Did you get any exception?

Comment: First try to launch and use SQL server profile and check whether the connection (ado.net) is connecting or hitting the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what happened but I just ran the application again to double check if an exception was thrown and get that message and not it is working. I have no idea why. Thank you for helping.